# .Net MAUI - How to bind to a property in an object that is a List of KeyValuePairs

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

Completely new to .Net MAUI.

I have the following "model" (application data) class that includes a property that is a list of KeyValuePair<String, String>, as shown below:

```
   public class app_data
   {

      private Int32 m_num_fld;

      private List<KeyValuePair<String, String>> m_kvp_list;


      public app_data()
      {

         m_num_fld = 100
      
         m_kvp_list = new List<KeyValuePair<String, String>>()
         {

            new KeyValuePair<String, String>( "Key 1", "Value 1" ),
            new KeyValuePair<String, String>( "Key 2", "Value 2" )

         };
         
      }


      public Int32 num_fld
      {

         get => m_num_fld;

         set => m_num_fld = value;

      }


      public List<KeyValuePair<String, String>> kvp_list
      {

         get => m_post_data_kv_list;

         set => m_post_data_kv_list = value;

      }

   }
```

Within XAML (shown below), how does one "bind" the kvp_list within app_data to show the keys and values? If someone can post a step-by-step example or link to a similar problem that would be extremely helpful.

```
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding ????? }">

        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>

                    <Grid
                        RowDefinitions="*,*"
                        ColumnDefinitions="3*, *"
                        RowSpacing="5">

                        <Label 
                            Text="{ ????? - HOW TO BIND TO Key in kvp_list }" 
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            BackgroundColor="White"
                            Padding="0,10,30,10"
                            />

                        <Label
                            Text="{Binding HOW TO BIND TO Value in kvp_list ????? }"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            BackgroundColor="LightGrey"
                            Padding="10,10,30,10"
                            Margin="10"
                            />

                    </Grid>

            </DataTemplate>

        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

    </CollectionView>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing all instances of **x:DataType=** from the page (as Jason suggested) did the trick -- why?  Who knows! It remains a mystery (for me at least) as I found nothing in the official docs that mentioned anything close to this "solution".

The official docs did suggest it is a good thing to use **x:DataType=** (and most examples in the docs do just that), as this results in [compiled bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings) which "*improve data binding performance*" and "*compile-time validation of binding expressions enables a better developer troubleshooting experience*" -- that is, if you can get it to work!

I have yet to find any official example that makes use of compiled bindings for a property such as:

```
   public List<KeyValuePair<String, String>> kvp_list { ... }
```

in which the "Key" and "Value" of the KeyValuePair is somehow made available via intellisense and provides compile-time validation.   Should someone with far more experience care to post such an example using the "app_data" model in the original post and include the XAML attributes that allow for compiled bindings, be my guest !

Answer (score -1):

[KeyValuePair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?view=net-6.0#properties) has two properties, `Key` and `Value` that you can use in your bindings

Comment: Yes - I know -- the problem is the "Key" and "Value" properties never show up!!  All I see is the List properties of "Count" and "Capacity".  No matter what I try, I can't seem to access the "Key" and "Value" properties of the KeyValuePair.

Comment: there is nothing in your post to indicate that you knew that.  What do you mean "never show up"?  Do you mean at runtime?  Or via Intellisense?  Are you using `DataType` in your XAML?

Comment: Hi Jason - sorry -- yes in Intellisense the only properties that show up are "Count" and "Capacity" -- so I am missing something with regard to binding.   Thanks.

Comment: that's because it doesn't know what the type for the DataTemplate is.  Either add a DataType attribute to the DataTemplate, or get rid of all the DataType attributes in the page

Comment: you can write XAML without Intellisense.  It is a design time helper only.  I never use `DataType` in my XAML.  Or did you try my other suggestion?

Comment: Will go back to the drawing board -- I just tried removing the "DataType" attribute from the page and now intellisense no longer contains the List object. Will keep plugging -- wish the docs were a bit more clear on describing how binding works (with more examples) -- very confusing for a first timer! Appreciate the push in the right direction though!

Comment: Tried adding a "DataType" attribute to the "DataTemplate", but intellisense will not allow it -- no such attribute. -- will consult the docs for further info.

Comment: it's `x:DataType`

Comment: Where are these tidbits in the docs?  -- I must be looking in the wrong place!!   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/datatemplate ? -- will keep hunting -- Thanks for the hints !

Comment: where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Appreciate your patience.  I am looking for some clear documentation or example that illustrates how values in an object (the app_data object in this case) are bound to elements in an XAML page.  Step-by-simpleton-Step -- I am finding bits and pieces in the docs, but nothing that clearly illustrates how the path is paved between the object / data and the XAML page.   I am stuck because (via intellisense) I can see the "Count" and "Capacity" properties of the list, but am missing some key syntax that makes the "Key" and "Value" visible in intellisense.   Just too green at this point !

Comment: read the Xamarin Forms docs on binding, it is the same basic mechanism used by MAUI.  I don't know if there is a clean way to specify a generic type like KVP in the DataType property.  You would be better off removing all DataTemplate attributes from this specific page.  Your code will still work without them, you just won't have Intellisense for the bindings.  Your binding paths should just be "{Binding Key}" and "{Binding Value}"